# Ant Junit ClassNotFoundException...again

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm aware they're are plenty of these but I just am not seeing the solution and all help would be very much appreciated. So trying to make an ant task to run my junit tests. Running into the ClassNotFoundException.

```
<property name="testsrc" value="${project.home}/../extensions/myaddon/testsrc"/>
<property name="src" value="${project.home}/../extensions/myaddon/src"/>
<property name="websrc" value="${project.home}/../extension/myaddon/acceleratoraddon/web/src"/>
<property name="junitLocation" value="${project.home}/../lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>

<path id="test-path">
    <pathelement location="${testsrc}"/>
    <pathelement location="${src}"/>
    <pathelement location="${websrc}"/>
    <pathelement location="${junitLocation}"/>
</path>
<!--
Batch testing
This will be used to test every test file we have rather than having to specify individual ones
-->
<target name="codtests" description="run all junit tests for myaddon">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test-path"/>
        </classpath>

        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${testsrc}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
    <echo message="batch testing done"/>
</target>
```

Stacktrace:

```
C:\tem\cnacc.cod>ant codtests
Buildfile: C:\tem\cnacc.cod\build.xml

codtests:
    [junit] Running codaddon.setup.CodSetupTest
    [junit] Testsuite: codaddon.setup.CodSetupTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] codaddon.setup.CodSetupTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: codaddon.setup.CodSetupTest
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    [junit]
    [junit] Test codaddon.setup.CodSetupTest FAILED
    [junit] Running codaddon.setup.FakeTest
    [junit] Testsuite: codaddon.setup.FakeTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] codaddon.setup.FakeTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: codaddon.setup.FakeTest
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    [junit]
    [junit] Test codaddon.setup.FakeTest FAILED
    [junit] Running codaddon.test.AutoPassTest
    [junit] Testsuite: codaddon.test.AutoPassTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] codaddon.test.AutoPassTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: codaddon.test.AutoPassTest
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    [junit]
    [junit] Test codaddon.test.AutoPassTest FAILED
    [junit] Running codaddon.test.Fake2Test
    [junit] Testsuite: codaddon.test.Fake2Test
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] codaddon.test.Fake2Test
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: codaddon.test.Fake2Test
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    [junit]
    [junit] Test codaddon.test.Fake2Test FAILED
     [echo] batch testing done

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

C:\tem\cnacc.cod>
```

Comment: Please ad full stacktrace to see which class is not found.

Comment: Sorry added the stacktrace there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point to test .class files, not sources. 
Compile your tests and add the folder to the *test-path*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be pasting the stacktrace. Perhaps as a wild guess, where have you defined the ${project.home} variable ? I see this is the only variable in the classpath which might not have resolved.

Comment: ${project.home} value is set to be "."